# attempted to read or write protected memory ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I get this error whenever I attempt to run a web app from the IDE.  I am using VS 2008 Team Edition, .Net Framework 3.5, SP1.  This literally occurs on a brand new app with no code it in it at all.  Just a default page.  I hit the run button, and I get the error message.  There is no break point, I don't get any error information, just the dialog box.

Comment: What do you see in the Call Stack window?

Answer (score 1):

Click Debug, Exceptions, tell it to break on everything, then try again and give us more detail.

Comment: I have it set to break on everything.  I get the error dialog box described above.

Answer (score 0):

are you running it in the webdev server that visual studio uses automatically or have you set it up to use IIS? If IIS, what version is it?

Comment: Yes, I am running this in the VS webdev server.